# Error: ...cker/start/lsp-zero.nvim/lua/lsp-zero/nvim-cmp-setup.lua:12: attempt to index field 'SelectBehavior' (a nil value)

Tags: neovim, plugin-nvim-cmp

I'm getting:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/dstromberg/.vim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...cker/start/lsp-zero.nvim/lua/lsp-zero/nvim-cmp-setup.lua:12: attempt to index field 'SelectBehavior' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...cker/start/lsp-zero.nvim/lua/lsp-zero/nvim-cmp-setup.lua:12: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...im/site/pack/packer/start/lsp-zero.nvim/lua/lsp-zero.lua:32: in function 'setup'
        /Users/dstromberg/.vim/init.lua:35: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

...with the following `~/.vim/init.lua`:

```
-- vim.opt.tabstop = 4
-- vim.opt.shiftwidth = 4
-- vim.opt.softtabstop = 4
-- vim.opt.expandtab = true

require('packer').startup(function(use)
    use {
        -- packer can manage itself
        'wbthomason/packer.nvim',
        'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
        requires = {
            -- LSP Support
            {'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'},
            {'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
            {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'},

            -- Autocompletion
            {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'},
            {'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'},
            {'hrsh7th/cmp-path'},
            {'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip'},
            {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'},
            {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua'},

            -- Snippets
            {'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip'},
            {'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets'},
        }
    }
end)

local lsp = require('lsp-zero')

lsp.preset('recommended')
lsp.setup()
```

I'm just getting started with Neovim; this hasn't worked for me previously.

I'm using:

```
$ nvim --version
cmd output started 2022 Wed Dec 28 01:08:28 PM PST
NVIM v0.8.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by brew@Monterey

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.8.1/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

On an Intel Mac:

```
$ sw_vers 
cmd output started 2022 Wed Dec 28 01:09:39 PM PST
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.6
BuildVersion:   21G115
```

Also, I'm using today's packer 'master' branch. `:PackerSync` inside Neovim says `Everything already up to date!`

My ultimate goal is to get LSP working with Python and bash, and probably others as needed.  I really like the sound of Mason taking care of that for me - if/when it works.

Any suggestions?  I've googled for hours, but didn't find much other than people saying "It just works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the module for nvim-cmp was not loaded properly. Make sure nvim-cmp is installed and is accesible. You can execute the command `:lua require('cmp')` and if that throws an error it means something went wrong during the installation of nvim-cmp.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened because I just recently updated my plugins (including nvim-cmp). They changed the parameters that went into cmp.select_prev_item() and cmp.select_next_item() ...or maybe I mistyped them?

I suggest you type `:help cmp` and search by typing `/select_` to check out the different usages and parameters allowed.

PS: if you have just updated your plugins, restart your Neovim to load up the updated docs... very important.